# Content Security Policy - Can I explicitly block a domain so I don't get an error for a known resource

Tags: content-security-policy

I've recently implemented a content security policy.

I'm currently loading FontAwesome via their CDN and they are attempting to inject and load this file which I don't want to allow.

`Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.fontawesome.com/js/stats.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ...`

The thing is I know I don't want to allow this resource through and hence don't want it generating console errors any longer.

**Is there a way to update a CSP to activley block or blacklist domains/URLS?**

Comment: You browser’s already actively blocking that script from loading, due to your your CSP policy not explicitly allowing it. So your CSP policy’s already having the end effect of stopping that script from loading. Any time a CSP policy prevents a resource for loading, your browser’s going to log a message like that. That’s the way CSP works. That message is not an error message—it’s just a log message to tell what effects your CSP policy is having. If you don’t want that message logged, then you need to use something other than a CSP policy to cause that—or else don’t use the FontAwesome CDN.

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification, I suppose wishful thinking leads me to wanting to be able to effectively whitelist and blacklist, but cheers, you've just saved me a bunch of further searching.

Comment: If you want to add your original comment as an answer I can close this question and give you the accepted answer :)

Comment: OK now graduated it to an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser’s already actively blocking the script from loading, due to your CSP policy not explicitly allowing it. So your CSP policy’s already having the end effect of stopping that script from loading.

Any time a CSP policy prevents a resource for loading, your browser’s going to log a message like that. That’s the way CSP works. That message isn’t an error message—it’s just a log message to tell what effects your CSP policy is having. If you don’t want that message logged, then you need to use something other than a CSP policy to cause that—or else don’t use the FontAwesome CDN.